# Creating a repeating alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

How can I create a multiple repeating alarm. As an example I have created an alarm at 4:30 PM , and I want to repeat it in each Sunday, Monday and Thursday. I can schedule periodic alarm like repeat after interval , but how can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is an example of adding an alarm once a month.

```
 private void setAlarmForOneMonth() {

    AlarmManager mAlarmMgr = (AlarmManager) CONTEXT.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(CONTEXT, YOURALARMRECEIVERCLASS);

    PendingIntent mAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(CONTEXT, ONE_MONTH_ALARM, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mAlarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, getDuration(), mAlarmIntent);
}
```

private long getDuration() {

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int updatedMonthValue = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, updatedMonthValue);

    return calendar.getTimeInMillis(); // this is what you set as trigger point time i.e one month after

}
```

Also you can read more on this link [Alarm Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)